# Adding more classes to a prewritten program

Tags: java

I am being tasked with adding 2 more classes to a prewritten program, one that does all calculations and one that prints the total bill. I understand how to add other classes but im a bit confused since the program already looks like it does the calculations inside of the main class.

Ive tried just adding in the classes but it throws errors because its missing information obviously.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String squantity, snumber, output, line_output = "";
    String [] item = new String [5];
    double [] cost = new double [5];
    double [] quantity = new double [5];
    double [] amount = new double [5];
    int number, i;
    double grandtotal = 0;
    String costout, amountout, grandtotalout;
    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("$##,###.00");

    for(i=0;i<=4;++i)
    {
        output = "   Acme Grocery Store" + "\n" +
           "1-Green Beans $0.35 per pound" + "\n" +
           "2-Yellow Beans $0.40 per pound" + "\n" +
           "3-Head Lettuce $0.79 per pound" + "\n" +
           "4-Leaf Lettuce $1.98 per pound" + "\n" +
           "5-Hot House Tomatoes $0.99 per pound" + "\n" +
           "6-Hydro Tomatoes $3.98 per pound" + "\n" + "\n" +
           "Please make your selection ";

        snumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                output, "Input Data", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        number = Integer.parseInt(snumber);
        squantity = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter Quantity", "Input Data", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        quantity[i] = Double.parseDouble(squantity);

        //code for the calculation
        if(number == 1)
        {
            cost[i] = 0.35;
            item[i]="Green Beans";
        }
        else if(number == 2)
        {
            cost[i] = 0.4;
            item[i]="Yellow Beans";
        }
        else if(number == 3)
        {
            cost[i] = 0.79;
            item[i]="Head Lettuce";
        }
        else if(number ==4)
        {
            cost[i] = 1.98;
            item[i]="Leaf Lettuce";
        }
        else if (number==5)
        {
            cost[i] = 0.99;
            item[i]="Hot House Tomatoes";
        }
        else
        {
            cost[i] = 3.98;
            item[i]="Hydro Tomatoes";
        }

        amount[i]=cost[i]*quantity[i];
        costout=df2.format(cost[i]);
        amountout=df2.format(amount[i]);
        line_output=line_output+item[i]+"  "+costout+"  "+amountout+"\n";
        grandtotal=grandtotal + amount[i];
    }//for loop

    grandtotalout=df2.format(grandtotal);
    output=line_output+"\n"+ "The total grocery bill = "+grandtotalout;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, " ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    System.exit(0);
}//main
```

We are expected to add the classes

```
class grocery {
}

class printbill{
}
```

I tried messing with the extends function but I dont think that is correct either

Comment: Is the purposes of the classes, to refactor and encapsulate some part of the logic of the application? Possibly if refactored in this way, that logic will be easier to swap out for different logic later.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, your grocery class would look something like this:

```
final class Grocery
{
    Grocery(String InputItem, double InputCost, double InputQuantity)
    {
         Item = InputItem;
         Cost = InputCost;
         Quantity = InputQuantity;
    }

    public final String GetItem()
    {
         return Item;
    }

    public final double GetCost()
    {
        return (double)InputQuantity * Cost; 
    }

    private final String Item;
    private final double Cost;
    private final int Quantity;
}
```

The PrintBill class may go like this:

```
final class PrintBill
{
    PrintBill(Grocery [] InputGroceries)
    {
         Groceries = InputGroceries;
    }

    public final void Print()
    {
         double Cost, TotalCost = 0.0;
         String Line = "";
         String Item;

         for (int i = 0; i < Groceries.length; i++)
         {
              Cost = Groceries[i].GetCost();
              Item = Groceries[i].GetItem();
              TotalCost += Cost;

              // I'll leave it up to you to print this info out. 
              Line = Item + "  " + Cost +"  "+ TotalCost +"\n";
         }

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, " ", 
                         JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }


    private final Grocery [] Groceries;
}
```

Your main() would then be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String squantity, snumber, output, line_output = "";
    Grocery [] Groceries = new Grocery [4];
    PrintBill TheBill;
    int number;

    for (int i = 0; i < Groceries.length; i++)
    {
        output = "   Acme Grocery Store" + "\n" +
                 "1-Green Beans $0.35 per pound" + "\n" +
                 "2-Yellow Beans $0.40 per pound" + "\n" +
                 "3-Head Lettuce $0.79 per pound" + "\n" +
                 "4-Leaf Lettuce $1.98 per pound" + "\n" +
                 "5-Hot House Tomatoes $0.99 per pound" + "\n" +
                 "6-Hydro Tomatoes $3.98 per pound" + "\n" + "\n" +
                 "Please make your selection ";

         snumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                  output, "Input Data", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
         number = Integer.parseInt(snumber);
         squantity = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                 "Enter Quantity", "Input Data", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
         quantity = Double.parseDouble(squantity);

         if(number == 1)
         {
             Groceries[i] = new Grocery("Green Beans", 0.35, quantity);
         }
         else if(number == 2)
         {
             Groceries[i] = new Grocery("Yellow Beans", 0.4, quantity);
         }
         // etc...

    }

    TheBill = new PrintBill(Groceries);

    TheBill.Print(); 

}
```

More work is required to actually complete this but it should give you a starting point anyway.

Happy Days :-)